# Custom notification in Intellij reacting to string in console

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Is it possible to create custom notifications in Intellij? For example: I run script  in Intellij console and want to get notified when string "are available for use" is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by writing a plugin that contains an implementation of the [Filter](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/execution/filters/Filter.java) interface and a [ConsoleFilterProvider](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/execution/filters/ConsoleFilterProvider.java) that will instantiate your Filter.

Comment: The Filter link has since been moved to
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/execution/src/com/intellij/execution/filters/Filter.java